# Getting all entries from N unique users

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with Google BigQuery and I have two tables as described by the following link:
[[Tables]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcLBb.png).

- **user_metric** contains entries with the lifetime information of all users.
- **user_daily_metric** contains entries for each user and each of the days they have been active

My challenge is that I wish to take the first 500 unique users (represented by the candidate key **user_metric.userid**) and I want to create a table with entries for each of these 500 unique users and all of their days active. Resulting in a table similar to this: [[Resulting table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an0ff.png)

(Consider the user with userid = 0690894780 as not being a part of the first 500 unique users)

My current query works for creating the table I desire, in terms of columns, but I have not been able to figure out how to limit it to only entries from the 500 unique users.

**Current query:**

```
SELECT
  user_metrics.userid, user_metrics.userProgression, user_daily_metrics.missionSecondsPlayed_sum, user_daily_metrics.missionMovesUsed_sum
FROM
  user_metric
JOIN user_daily_metric
ON user_metric.userid = user_daily_metric.userid
ORDER BY
user_metrics.userid
```

In advance, thank you very much for taking the time to read my question (and if I'm lucky, even reply to it) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT um.userid, um.userProgression, user_daily_metrics.missionSecondsPlayed_sum,  
       udm.missionMovesUsed_sum
FROM (SELECT um.*
      FROM user_metric um
      ORDER BY um.userid
      LIMIT 500
     ) um JOIN
     user_daily_metric udm
     ON um.userid = udm.userid
ORDER BY um.userid
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, this solved my problem.

Admittedly in the select statement of the subquery I had to use "user_metric" rather than "um", but that was easily resolved :)